# I want to plot data in the same point of 2 dates

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I wrote codes

```
test ='test.csv'
test = pd.read_csv(test)

test1 =‘test1.csv'
test1 = pd.read_csv(test1)
```

test shows

```
Date                Score
2010-01-01             20    
2010-01-02            30
2010-01-03            40
2010-01-04            50
```

test1 shows

```
Date            Score
2010-01-01        10    
2010-01-03        40
2010-01-04       30
2010-01-10        60
```

I wrote codes,

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import plotly
    import plotly.graph_objs as go
    import datetime

    import plotly.offline as offline
    plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=False)

    test ='test.csv'
    test = pd.read_csv(test)
    test =test["Score"]

    test1 ="test1.csv"
    test1 = pd.read_csv(test1)
    test1 =test1["Score"]

    data = [
            plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(y = test, mode = 'lines', name = 'TEST'),
            plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(y = test1, mode = 'lines', name = 'TEST2', yaxis='y2'),
        ]

    layout = plotly.graph_objs.Layout(
        title="test",
        xaxis={"title":"test"},
        yaxis={"title":"test1"},
        yaxis2={"title":"test2", "overlaying":"y", "side":"right"},
        )

        fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
        plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

I want to plot test & test1 data has same date in same x axis.For example,
test’s 2010-01-01’s 20   &  test1’s 2010-01-01’s 10 will be plotted in  same x axis.So,if date is paused of lacking of data, it is ok only plot circle but lines graph.
How can I do it?What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: read this documentation page [https://python-graph-gallery.com/122-multiple-lines-chart/](https://python-graph-gallery.com/122-multiple-lines-chart/)

Comment: @AkashBadam Iread it.But I cannot find how I should write codes to do my ideal things.

Comment: ideal things like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `data`, Check the following to get the resulted output with dual y axis for `test` and `test1` as below:

```
test['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(test['Date'])
test
Date    Score
0   2010-01-01  20
1   2010-01-02  30
2   2010-01-03  40
3   2010-01-04  50

test1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(test1['Date'])
test1
    Date    Score
0   2010-01-01  10
1   2010-01-03  40
2   2010-01-04  30
3   2010-01-10  60

import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import datetime

import plotly.offline as offline
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=False)

data = [go.Scatter(x = test.Date , y = test.Score , mode = 'lines', name = 'TEST'),
        go.Scatter(x = test1.Date, y = test1.Score, mode = 'lines', name = 'TEST2', 
                   yaxis='y2')]
layout = go.Layout(title="test",
                   xaxis={"title":"test"},
                   yaxis={"title":"test1"},
                   yaxis2={"title":"test2", "overlaying":"y", "side":"right"})

fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

The graph looks like this

[image]